# $where in Module: mongodb in npm not work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongo-shell

I am newbie about mongodb. My application is using *nodejs* *express* and *mongodb*. I am using  **Module: mongodb in npm** to connect and manipulate mongodb database from backend side. I insert the following documents to collection named products:

```js
async function insert (collection){
   const now = new Date()
   now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear()+2000)
    const data = await collection.insertMany([
         { title:  "banana", exp:now},
         { title:  "icecream", exp:now},
         { title:  "bread", exp:now},
      ]);
    return data;
}
```

after that i have the item in product collection:

[image: data sample]

However, when i using $where operator in the find method to get all product item have expired, i get all product (which have not expired yet). the following is my code to query:

```js
async function find(collection){
  const now = new Date()
  console.log('at now: ',now)
  const data =  await collection.find({
    $where: function () {
          return this.exp < new Date();
        },
  }).toArray()
return data;
}
```

Output i had gotten:

[image: output_1]

as you can see, the output is not what i'm expected. I have using mongosh (***mongo Shell***) to test it and the output mongo shell return my just **empty array** ( which i'm expected):

```bash
>db.product.find({ $where: function () { return this.exp < new Date(); } }).toArray()

[]
```

I have the question that, something's wrong happen in here, and how can i fix it?

Comment: i don't find anything wrong with the code you are getting what you wanted $where to return, new Date() is always greater than you previously saved date. what you want your code to return instead?

Comment: @Phil as you can see, all the document in my collection have the year in *exp* field is 4023. However, now is 2023 so when i run the query code it is expected to return empty array ( []), the result i get is list of items which have exp field in year 4023

Comment: @Phil when i run the find function to query all item that have exp field is the date had pass

Comment: At a glance I'm not sure why you observe the discrepancy, though it's possible it has to do with how node is interpreting that function. In any case, can you also clarify why you are using `$where`? The example you've provided certainly doesn't need it and it's best to avoid that operator in general as it is not very performant

Comment: @user20042973 in my real application the exp field is **string**, its type is not Date object. I choose string to be type of that field simply because timezone in my country is not +00:00, so i have used toString() method of Date object to get date-time which match to my timezone. When type of **exp** field is string and i want ot get all item of product have expired, i decide to use **$where** operator solve my query requirement because **exp** is string, not Date object

Comment: You may want to store `exp` as a [Date and also store the time zone](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/model-time-data/#:~:text=MongoDB%20stores%20times%20in%20UTC,time%20in%20their%20application%20logic.).